# Clojure Heroku web-app: page won't render in browser

Tags: heroku, clojure, routes, rendering

I am trying to make a webapp that helps teachers to calculate their grades online. I used the lein new heroku command to make it and am having trouble getting my routers sorted and the front page to render. Any help would be appreciated! Here is what my defroutes looks like. It is in the web.clj file in the same folder as the page I want to have rendered:

```
(ns clojuregrade.web
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET PUT POST DELETE ANY]]
            [compojure.handler :refer [site]]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [ring.middleware.stacktrace :as trace]
            [ring.middleware.session :as session]
            [ring.middleware.session.cookie :as cookie]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [ring.middleware.basic-authentication :as basic]
            [cemerick.drawbridge :as drawbridge]
            [environ.core :refer [env]]))

 (defroutes app
      (ANY "/repl" {:as req}
           (drawbridge req))
      (GET "/" []
           {:status 200 ;; <- this is where it says the error is showing up
            :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
            :body (pr-str (slurp (io "landing.clj"))) ;; <- I am guessing here
      (ANY "*" []
           (route/not-found (slurp (io/resource "404.html"))))
```

This is the code with the page I would like to have rendered:

```
(ns clojuregrade.landing
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET PUT POST DELETE ANY]]
            [compojure.handler :refer [site]]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [ring.middleware.stacktrace :as trace]
            [ring.middleware.session :as session]
            [ring.middleware.session.cookie :as cookie]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [hiccup.core :refer :all]
            ))

           ...

(defn home [& [weights grades error]]
      (layout/common
        [:h1 "Welcome to Clojure-grade"]

        [:hr]

        (form-to [:post "/"]

                 [:p "Enter the weights for your various grades below. For example if you have quizzes, homework and tests
                  and they are worth 40% 10% and 50% respectively, you can enter: [40 10 50].
                  Of course, all of the numbers should add up to 100%. Be sure to include the brackets"
                  (text-field {:placeholder "[40 10 50]"} "weights" weights)]

                 [:p "Enter ALL of the grades for EACH STUDENT in your class.
                  Make sure that each of the grades is ordered such that the grade corresponds
                  to its matching weight above. Use brackets to separate students from each other.
                  Each set of grades should have the same number of grades as the number of possible weights (3 in this example case).
                  The following example shows grades for 4 students. Format your grades according to the number of students in your class:"
                  (text-area {:rows 40 :cols 40 :placeholder
                              "[89 78 63]
                               [78 91 60]
                               [54 85 91]
                               [100 89 77]
                              ..."  } "grades" grades)]
                 (submit-button "process"))))

    (defn process-grades [weights grades]
    (->> (float grades)
         (map (partial percentify-vector (float weights)))
         (mapv #(apply + %))))

    (defroutes app
      (GET "/" []
           {:status 200  
            :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
            :body home})
      (POST "/" [weights grades] ((process-grades (read-string weights) (read-string grades)) ))
      (ANY "*" []
           (route/not-found (slurp (io/resource "404.html")))))

    (defn wrap-error-page [handler]
      (fn [req]
        (try (handler req)
             (catch Exception e
               {:status 500
                :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
                :body (slurp (io/resource "500.html"))}))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.  First off, you have `(io "landing.clj")`, which as far as I can tell `io` refers to a namespace, not a valid var.  But even if you had `(io/resource "landing.clj")` (and landing.clj was in the resources directory), this would simply dump the contents of landing.clj (i.e., the source code) to the browser ... probably not what you want.

You need to call `clojuregrade.landing/home`.  You could do this directly from the "/" route in `clojuregrade.web`.  You could also (what I think you intend to do), have the "/" route in `clojuregrade.web` dispatch to the routes handler in `clojuregrade.landing` (i.e., call `clojuregrade.landing/app`).  You might also find https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Nesting-routes useful.

BTW, your "/" route in `clojuregrade.landing` looks *almost* correct.  You might want to actually call `home`, however, instead of returning a reference to the function:

```
(GET "/" []
       {:status 200  
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
        :body (home)}) ;; <-- Note parentheses -- (home) instead of home
```

There's probably still more you need to do to get a working application.  If you haven't already, please work through at least one Ring/Compojure tutorial to at least get a working app, then apply what you learned.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will implement your suggestions and do more tutorials. I am brand new to everything: code, Clojure and web-development. The learning curve is quite steep. I am currently working through the Web Development with Clojure book and have read the Ring and Compojure overviews on Github top to bottom. I have done several tutorials and am now trying to take baby steps into doing something myself. Pulling it all together is quite a challenge, though. Any solid (up to date) tutorial recommendations that REALLY explain the details I need would be appreciated.